# High Thread Count and CPU utilization by Eureka Discovery server, after upgrading to new SpringBoot and Cloud Version

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-netflix

Recently we upgraded our SpringBoot and Cloud Version of Eureka Discovery Server App, post upgrade we are experiencing high Thread count and high CPU utilization.

What would have triggered this ? Are we missing any performance tuning with new version? We are using default configuration values for discovery-server.

Prior to upgrade the CPU utilization was around 30%, post upgrade it's shot up to around 80%, and there is no increase in Number of application registering on Eureka.

Here are some more details:

```
Upgraded version:
springBootVersion = "2.1.2.RELEASE"
springCloudVersion = 'Greenwich.RELEASE'

Previous version:
springBootVersion = "1.5.6.RELEASE"
springCloudVersion = 'Dalston.SR4'
```

These are some metrics from actuator on upgraded version:

```
server.tomcat.maxThreads    200
server.tomcat.maxConnections    10000

actuator/metrics/tomcat.threads.config.max  200
actuator/metrics/tomcat.threads.current     200
actuator/metrics/jvm.threads.live           260
actuator/metrics/jvm.threads.daemon         257
actuator/metrics/jvm.threads.peak           261
actuator/metrics/jvm.gc.pause(count)        5750 (for two days of Uptime)
```

Allocated memory is 1Gb and used memory is within the limit.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: None that I know of. There are later versions of boot and cloud that you might try. What OS?

Comment: Deployed on Linux  (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago), 2 core)

Comment: I can reproduce this problem with Spring cloud native Stack. 

It seams a problem with Eureka discovery service since Greenwich Time together with config server. A Eureka discovery service with Spring Boot 2 fetches 50% of CPU and raises also the CPU time of our Config server.

If I downgrade the Eureka server to a build with Spring boot 1.5, everything is back to normal.

Spring boot 2.1.4.RELEASE, Greenwich.SR1 come with high CPU usage.
1.5.15.RELEASE, Edgware.SR4 works ok.